# Showing that integral gets smaller as measure gets smaller (epsilon-delta)

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the measure space $(X,A,\mu)$ and let $u \in M^+(A)$. Assume that $  \int_{{X}}^{}  u  \,d\mu\  < \infty$.

Show that for every $\varepsilon >0 $ some $\delta >0 $ exists such that for all $ E \in A  $ the following identity holds:

$ \mu(E)< \delta \Rightarrow \int_{{E}}^{}  u  \,d\mu\ < \varepsilon $

Edit: I think I got it now.

$  \int_{{X}}^{}  u  \,d\mu\  < \infty$ implies that $u$ is bounded by some $k\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $u<k$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R} $. Then $u \mathbb{1}_E \leq k \mathbb{1}_E $. Choose $\delta=\varepsilon/k$. Then we have:

$ \int_{{E}}^{}  u  \,d\mu \leq k\int_{{}}^{}  \mathbb{1}_E  \,d\mu=k\mu(E)<k\delta=\varepsilon $

Does it look right?

Comment: Use this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261787/showing-that-nu-ll-mu-implies-forall-epsilon-0-exists-delta-0?rq=1

Comment: Thank you. I just edited my post.

Comment: $u$ needs not be bounded. $1/\sqrt{x}$ is integrable on $(0,1)$ but not bounded.

Comment: This is a classic exercise in using dominated convergence. Consider $\phi_n(x)=\max(-n,\min(f(x),n)$. This sequence $\\phi_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ and so in $L-1$ by dominated convergence. One can then write $|\int_Af|\leq|\int_A(f-\phi_N)|+|\int_A\phi_N|\leq\int_X|f-\phi_N|+\int_A|\phi_N|\leq \int_A|f-\phi_N|+N\mu(A) I$. hope this helps.